# socket.io force disconnect client

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I may be doing something wrong here but I can't get my head around this.

The following does not work:

**client**

```
$("#disconnectButton").click(function() {
  socket.emit("disconnect");
});
```

**server**

```
socket.on("disconnect", function() {
  console.log("this never gets called");
});
```

Can't I manually call the disconnect event from the client side? Because the following works:

**client**

```
$("#disconnectButton").click(function() {
  socket.emit("whatever");
});
```

**server**

```
socket.on("whatever", function() {
  socket.disconnect();
  console.log("this gets called and disconnects the client");
});
```

Comment: What is your reasoning for forcing the disconnect?  If you are trying to boot someone for violating limits or security restrictions, you should kill the connection less gracefully.

Comment: I have a chat app where I'd like to add a 'disconnect' option - so that someone can manually disconnect from the websocket (kind of like replicating if users were to hit refresh.)

Answer (score 9):

'disconnect' event is Socket.io event,if you use emit to call the 'disconnect',may be cause other problom

so:

```
$("#disconnectButton").click(function() {
  socket.emit("disconnect");
});
```

replace:

```
$("#disconnectButton").click(function() {
  socket.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't call the `disconnect` event for me.

Answer (score 1):

For now, `socket.emit('disconnect')` or `socket.disconnect()` doesn't work.
The correct syntax to disconnect to the socket server is

```
socket.close()
```